# I'm not able to make this program draw figures towards left & up. It only draws to right and down

Tags: java

I'm having problem drawing rectangle to the left and upwards. They draw perfect to right and downwards.
An answer would be highly appreciated.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ch10_Ex04_Mouse_Dragged_Rectangle extends GraphicsProgram
{

    public void init()
    {
    addMouseListeners();
    }

    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
    {
      X = e.getX();
      Y = e.getY();
      rect = new GRect (e.getX(), e.getY(), 0, 0);
      add (rect);
    }

    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e) 
    {
    //  if (e.getX() < X)
    //  rect.setBounds(X, Y, -e.getX() + X, e.getY() - Y);
        rect.setBounds(X, Y, e.getX()-X, e.getY()-Y);
    }

    int X, Y;
    private GRect rect;

}
```

Comment: This is not a program. This is just a class. That said, you need to look up the documentation for rect.setBounds. I'm pretty sure that giving it negative width and/or height is actually not allowed, but you're going to have to look it up and tell me if that's the case, because if you don't know, you haven't looked up the documentation yet, and you probably should have held off asking on stack overflow until you were sure you called all your functions correctly =)

Comment: I am guessing this also does not work for dragging (1) left and down and (2) right and up.  Posted an answer that takes into account all 4 drag directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making some assumptions here, but I think this is the mouseDragged function you are looking for (I did not validate this for syntax errors).  This should draw the rectangle in all four possible drag directions (1) right/down, (2) right/up, (3) left/down, (4) left/up:

```
public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e) 
{
    // Determine x-val and length
    int xPos = X;
    int xLen = Math.abs(X - e.getX());
    if (e.getX() < X) {
        xPos = e.getX();
    }

    // Determine y-val and length
    int yPos = Y;
    int yLen = Math.abs(Y - e.getY());
    if (e.getY() < Y) {
        yPos = e.getY();
    }

    // Set bounds on rectangle
    rect.setBounds(xPos, yPos, xLen, yLen);
}
```

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.  The trick is to determine the left-most X val and the top-most Y val.  After that you just plug in lengths.  This code could be simplified, but wrote it this way for readability.